# Polygons not filling correctly in c#

Tags: c#, polygon

I have a bunch of areas that I want to build as polygons on a map,even though the points are on the right places, the areas does not fill correctly, is that a limitation of the polygons or is there a solution? If not, what do you recommend I use for this?

```cs
//for each NUT2 area
foreach (var Nut in allareas.features)
{
    //add the coordinates which is a list to the Polygon
    var polygon = new GMapPolygon(Nut.coordinates, Nut.id);
    polygon.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    //colour stuff
    polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.BurlyWood);

    var polygons = new GMapOverlay("Polygons");
    polygon.Tag = Nut.na;
    polygon.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    polygons.Polygons.Add(polygon);
    gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(polygons);
}
```

An example of the result:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Looks like the points are correct but are either out of order or shouldn't be connected. Check your source data step-by-step on some isolated problem areas.

Comment: I think your points are out-of-order.  Polygon points must always be in a proper order, usually clock-wise.

Comment: I did consider that, But there are a LOT of points, so I was avoiding that.

Comment: I have figured out the issue, There are some regions which are the same region but is not physically connected, so instead of making 2 or 3 polygons there is just one which is a mess, Will be easier to fix